# Real time report generate issue

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

We are developing a application has 2.2 million customers. We develop rest api. Transaction report api hit huge table to generate a complex report. If a single time more than 100k customers get this data huge hit my database server. My question is which way we generate report without hit SQL server database. Or world best organization how to manage this type of application database.
We use asp.net mvc5 and SQL server

Comment: Have you exhausted all avenues around indexes, partitioning? What kind of latency can you handle (1 second? 1 minute?) Does the report need to cross all of the data?

Comment: Nick. My thinking is, if I store data 2 separate database one is SQL server other is elasticsearch. Then all report i generate from eleasticSearch . Is it good decision

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use Indian words here. People will definitely get confused about what is a "22lac customer".

Comment: It depends on the type of reports and how much latency you can deal with. Neither of which are described.

Comment: An elastic search report is very different to a relational report. What is this complex report? Is it an aggregate of figures or is it text?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two standard methods to "generate report without hit SQL server database".

- use snapshot isolation in the same OLTP database to avoid the report locking other writing transactions and ensure to get consistent data
- use the data transferred (ETL, log shipping, replication...) from OLTP to other (OLAP) database (i.e. to a warehouse or later in datamarts/cubes)

Answer (score 0):

you can have install other SQL instance  in prod and create transition replication on the database. Report on the replicated side on the database.